# Spring Cloud data flow documentation

Tags: spring-xd, spring-cloud-dataflow

Any update on when the Spring Cloud Data Flow documentation will be ready for prime time. It is really hard to plan for any significant deployment in the future, without complete developer documentation. Since Spring Cloud Data Flow draws off Spring XD heavily, would using Spring XD documentation till we get this complete, help in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the interest in the project.

> It is really hard to plan for any significant deployment in the future, without complete developer documentation

We have recently assembled all the important documentation fragments and are now available at Spring Cloud Data Flow's individual server implementations [*eg: [Spring Cloud Data Flow's Cloud Foundry Server Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#index)*].

For convenience, we have also added pointers to all various implementations and the corresponding reference guides to the [project page](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#spring-cloud-data-flow-server-implementations). We have plans to add project pages for individual server implementations, too.

> Since Spring Cloud Data Flow draws off Spring XD heavily, would using Spring XD documentation till we get this complete, help in any way?

Though the underlying goals/vision is largely same, fundamentally, Spring Cloud Data Flow is an entire rewrite and the orchestration of streams and tasks/batch pipelines requires a runtime platform like Cloud Foundry. More details in this blog [here](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/introducing-spring-cloud-data-flow).